# RDWeb authentication and MFA with Azure

Tags: .net, azure, iis, rds, multi-factor-authentication

I am recently trying to enable Azure AD authentication and Azure MFA for my company RDS environment. I am trying to do this in 'RDWeb' login layer. I want to enable Azure Ad authentication and then MFA, when someone browse "RDWeb". I tried several ways, but I couldn't accomplish that.

1 )I have created 'App Registration' -> url = https://rds.example.com/RDWeb (Redirect URI)

2.)In my web.config page

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DefaultCentralPublishingPort" value="5504" />
    <add key="WorkspaceID" value="rds.example.com" />
    <add key="WorkspaceName" value="" />
    <add key="WorkspaceDescription" value="" />
    <add key="ws08r2rdserver" value="" />
    <add key="radcmserver" value="rds.example.com" />
    <add key="ClientId" value="97exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="Tenant" value="common" />
  <add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
  <add key="redirectUri" value="https://rds.example.com/RDWeb/Pages/en-US/Default.aspx" />
</appSettings>
```

But When I tried to browse, it is showing default RDWeb and behavior and using with default windows authentication. Appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: The MFA Server would definitely have to be installed on each RD Web server so that it can hook into IIS on each server. Also, each MFA Server must be able to connect out to the Azure MFA cloud service over https.. you could refer some of the links:[link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5de7b027-921a-4b4f-9aa5-e4f55f00b9db/azure-mfa-rd-gateway-rd-web-access-and-single-sign-on-is-it-possible?forum=winserverTS) , [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/bbace057-6757-4df9-94d6-1b3c707a04cb/mfa-with-rdweb?forum=windowsazureactiveauthentication)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal: Thanks for your answer, I did not try to use MFA Server.because "July 1, 2019, Microsoft will no longer offer MFA Server for new deployments. New customers who would like to require multi-factor authentication from their users should use cloud-based Azure Multi-Factor Authentication"
I will try this and let you know - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfaserver-iis)

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal: sorry for the late reply. still having the same issue

Comment: @JalpaPanchal - I have deployed this same RDS environment using azure application proxy. In that way I did not have to alter the code. But I have to uncomment & comment some codes in order to apply Windows authentication for the RDWeb.
1) https://www.vroege.biz/?p=2563
2) https://www.vroege.biz/?p=2462
3) https://www.vroege.biz/?p=2647
It is an old blog, however those configurations are still valid. And also if you found any way to publish the code via application registry. please let me know.
Thanks